# What is tested during Continuous Integration

Tags: unit-testing, testing, continuous-integration

I am a developer that never understood testing properly. I am reading up on unit testing, TDD, and other relevant topics that come up together since I am primarily trying to understand the concepts behind Continuous Integration.

What is particularly tested on a CI server? Is it just the unit tests written by the developers? Are testers in less demand since the CI is doing a lot of the heavy lifting here and are they still relevant?

Comment: I think this is a straightforward answer to your question:
[Running test on CI server](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/308517)

Answer (score 0):

CI (Continuous Integration) is not a replacement for testers. It simply ensures that every code check in does not break the application. There are plenty of different configurations that teams use. For example, in my workplace, each unit and integration test is run on every code checkin. Some teams choose to only run the unit tests each checkin, and run the integration tests at some other interval (maybe every night). Its up to the team to weight the benifits of when the tests are run on the CI with how long these tests may take and the resources it will require.